# Tridiagonal matrix with extra diagonals at sides

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I'm struggling with the construction of a matrix given below. I need to find a pattern to later on code it in Python and then solve a linear system of equations involving that matrix. Does that kind of a matrix have a special name?

$A \in R^{128x128}:
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ...\\
0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & ...\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & ...\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & ...\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & ...\\
.. & .. & .. & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Wikipedia calls it a [Band Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix). Since each diagonal is constant, this is also a Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: Just to be sure: the diagonals all hold the same value everywhere?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes, I assume so. I have no more info than I gave in question.  The main diagonal consists of 4s, any other diagonal consists of 1s

Comment: Fine. If you just want to build the matrix in Python, using numpy: `import numpy as np; n = 128; a = 4*np.eye(n) + np.diag(np.ones(n-1),1) + np.diag(np.ones(n-1),-1) + np.diag(np.ones(n-4),4) + np.diag(np.ones(n-4),-4)`